# What is the device shown in the picture below?

Tags: comparator

Is this a dynamic comparator?

I came across this circuit element while reading some IEEE papers. They looked like opamps/comparators but with 2 output lines.

The question is pretty noob but I just wanted to make sure its just that. [image]

Comment: Some context from those IEEE papers would be useful.

Comment: Tow-Thomas filter ,then a paper written by Snoeji on comparator for single slope ADC etc

Comment: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/6362fa.pdf -- Diff. op-amp

Answer (score 2):

It could be:

- operational amplifier
- buffer driver
- instrumentation amplifier

with differential output.

Comment: So basically its like the opamp symbol(triangle) , you can use it for any thing with two inputs and differential output? Not specifically opamp ? @Marko